# Why isn't the terminal velocity completely achieved but only asymptotically achieved due to action of resistive force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Motion against resistive forces is given by: $$F_0 - R(v) = m\frac{dv}{dt}$$ where $R(v) = A.v + B.v^2$. Terminal velocity can be found by solving $$B.v^2 + A.v - F_0 = 0$$ ie. $v_t$ is the velocity when $\sum \mathbf{F} = 0$. But it is written by A.P. French that:

> Note that the contrast between the sharply defined value of $v_t$ in the graph of $R(v)$ versus $v$, and the gradual manner in which the velocity is **approached but never quite, in principle, reached**.

Now, why can't it be reached?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Now, why can't it be reached?

The short answer is that, due to the nature of the equation of motion, if the particle velocity $v$ is the terminal velocity $v_t$ at *some* time $t$, then $v = v_t$ for *all* time $t$.

That is to say, a solution to the equation of motion is

$$v(t) = v_t$$

in which case, the acceleration is zero and thus, *the velocity is unchanging with time*.

It follows that if the velocity is not equal to $v_t$ at *some* time $t$, it's not equal to $v_t$ for *any* time $t$.

Comment: Hi, sir!(lately) You've written that if velocity is not the terminal one at some instant, it cannot be at any other instant. How 've you deduced this argument? I'm getting in the trouble. Plz help.

Comment: Velocity can be a mootonic function, right? So, after some time, it can have same value for consecutive instants. What is the problem with that?

Answer (score 1):

It's an *aymptotic* behavior. To understand the statement rigorously, you need to solve the differential equation to find velocity as a function of either time or distance travelled (to do the latter, write $\dot{v} = v\,\mathrm{d}_x\,v$ and you have a DE for $v$ as a function of $x$). However, physically, witness that as the object gets nearer and nearer to terminal velocity, the nett force on it gets nearer and nearer to nought (gravity becomes perfectly opposed by drag), so there is less and less tendency for the body's state of motion to change.

This kind of situation arises everywhere throughout physics as *stable systems approach their stable equilibrium points*. That this is a general behavior can be understood by stability theory and the study of so called stable fixed points: near any equilibrium point differential equation systems can be linearized and linear DEs are solved by superpositions of functions of time of the form $e^{\alpha_j\,t}$: the system is stable iff all the $\alpha_j$ have negative real parts, so you get the classic $e^{-t}$ dependence of "distance" from equilibrium versus time. Compare the situation to where your cup of tea is cooling down: as it approaches room temperature, there is less and less temperature gradient "driving" the heat transfer, so in theory it never quite reaches room temperature.

Comment: You are absolutely right that the temperature gradient becomes infinitesimally small as the tea approaches room temp. However, small the gradient might be, it does exist. So, why can't the tea reach the room temp?

Answer (score 0):

Because it's only a [limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)) for velocity, to which it will be continuously approaching by decreasing the difference between the actual velocity and this limit (and decreasing overall acceleration (**pace** of changing this velocity) **toward** zero).